# How to prevent redirection on sign out method?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, openid

When I am sign out using `await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` this code it's automatically redirecting on sign in page.

```
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:OpenIDDict:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:OpenIDDict:ClientSecret"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

                var authDomain = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Configuration["Domains:Auth"]) ?
                        $"auth.{Configuration["Domains:base"]}" :
                        Configuration["Domains:Auth"];

              
                options.Authority = $"https://{authDomain}";
               

                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Uri, ClaimTypes.Uri, "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, ClaimTypes.GivenName, "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, ClaimTypes.Surname, "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("Fullname", "Fullname", "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("Firstname", "Firstname", "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("Lastname", "Lastname", "string");

                options.SecurityTokenValidator = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
                {
                    // Disable the built-in JWT claims mapping feature.
                    InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                };

                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
                options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.Properties.RedirectUri);
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

This is my code for `AddAuthentication`.

`await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`
Using above code for sign out.

When I sign out its automatically redirecting on sign in page and I don't want to perform any redirection on sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete the last options in authentication:

```
options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.Properties.RedirectUri);
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
```

It is a redirecting after signing out.